# Get Windows 8 current accent colors from desktop app

Tags: c#, windows-8

I want get user specified metro colors, just for automatically adapt desktop app to main metro style. 
Any way to do that?

Comment: this may help: http://blog.quppa.net/2013/01/02/retrieving-windows-8-theme-colours/

Comment: Note of course that you need to let your customers know that your program intentionally calls undocumented APIs and therefore can stop working at any time.

Comment: @Raymond Or just fallback to some default colours.

Comment: @ChrisD How will you know that a fallback is needed? You called function 95. Maybe in a future version of Windows, function 95 reformats your hard drive.

Comment: @RaymondChen You won't add a function to format a hard drive in `uxtheme.dll`, will you? What if you import the function only if the current Windows version matches the versions you tested the function in?

Comment: @Elmo Clearly, reformatting the hard drive is extreme. But maybe function 95 changes all your colors to high contrast. If you import the function only if the current Windows matches the version you tested, then your app stops working at the next service pack, and your customers are not happy, and they will blame Microsoft for breaking your app.

Comment: @RaymondChen Devs should use undocumented behaviour only on tested platforms and use fallbacks for others, but that still leaves users unhappy I understand. Windows 10 ditches service packs and there isn't going to be any new Windows version so do people have to rely on the build number?

Comment: @Elmo Build number is not good enough. Updates can also alter functions. Unsupported functions are unsupported.

Comment: At this point I'm very curious because I can see both sides. Why on earth would Microsoft not provide a documented function for this? It's like not providing a documented way to get the active title bar color. Sometimes you just want your app to fit in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arman Stepanyan library is spot on but I decided to create a simple sample project which implements the color retrieving without the need of additional libraries. It was inspired by his library.

You can access it in GitHub here: https://github.com/VladimirAmiorkov/Windows-8-8.1-start-screen-colors-into-desktop-application

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. As I am a brand new user of stackoverflow I appreciate the constructive feedback and I will try to be more descriptive with my answers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jim O'Neil advise, I used it and write a little library with all currently known immersive colors list.
[Windows 8 Library](http://win8lib.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score -1):

There is no API available to use the currently selected Windows theme color.